# Запрос возвращает NULL при вызове web-сервиса

Tags: sql

```
declare @UserName nvarchar(100) = 'username1'
declare @Password nvarchar(100) = 'password1'
declare @uri nvarchar(800) = 'http://test.lan/portal'

declare @Object as Int;
declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object out;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @uri,'false', @UserName, @Password 
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText out
select @ResponseText
exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Заработало вот таким образом:

```
declare @Result int
declare @UserName nvarchar(100) = 'username1'
declare @Password nvarchar(100) = 'password1'
declare @uri nvarchar(800) = 'http://test.lan/portal'
    
declare @Object as Int;
declare @ResponseText as xml;
declare @xml table(Content xml)

exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object out;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @uri,'false', @UserName, @Password 
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'

insert into @xml(Content)
exec @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'

select * from @xml

exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: Вопрос в том, что не так с запросом?

Comment: после этого вызова @ResponseText равен NULL